# Bind two selectors, one for addClass and the other on to removeClass

Tags: jquery, html

As the title says, how to bind two selectors to open/close (add and remove class) on a div?

Simple HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="open">Open</a>
<div>
<span class="close">X</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Some jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var $open = $("a.open");
  var $close = $("span.close");
  $open.on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("active")) {
      $this.removeClass("active");
      $this.parent("div").removeClass("is-open");
    } else {
      $this.addClass("active");
      $this.parent("div").addClass("is-open");
    }
  });

  $close.on("click", function() {
    // This and only this close should remove the active class from the div and remove the active class from "a".

  });
});
```

Once again; if I click on "a" to open the div and then press "span" to close to div. Which is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
  $close.on("click", function() {
    var container = $(this).parent().parent();
    container.find(".active").removeClass("active");
    container.removeClass("is-open");

  });
```

Comment: @Flirt sure. Let me know the result :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```js
var $open = $("a.open");
var $close = $("span.close");
$open.on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass("active");
  $this.parent("div").addClass("is-open");
});
$close.on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.is-open').removeClass('is-open');
  $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.is-open {
  background: yellow;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="open">Open</a>
  <div>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```